# Error: Python not detecting file?

Tags: python

Right now I have created a folder and have a text file and a Python file. I'm trying to read the file into a string

```
fileName = 'file2.txt'
linestring = open(fileName, 'r').read()
print linestring
```

but I keep getting an error in return saying

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file2.text'
```

How do I get the two files into the same directory?

Comment: I guess it is `file2.txt` ?

Comment: That's the extent of my code right now. I'm learning dictionaries and I was going to test various files (more of a mental thing to see that each piece works).

Comment: Sorry, overlooked that! But still isn't found.

Comment: You said `How do I get the two files into the same directory` in your question. Do you mean they are not already in the same directory? If so, that's your problem

Comment: Is the file in the same directory as the python script?

Comment: @anmol_uppal you changed the intention of the post, don't do that

Comment: Could you show us your directory structure, and how you call this?

Comment: I assumed they were in the same directory (in the same folder on my desktop), but the error obviously indicates otherwise. If such is the problem, I'm asking how to have it so the python script is in the same file as the directory (or vice versa).

Comment: Ok sorry for that @TimCastelijns

Comment: Just create a new directory and copy paste both the files(Python script and text file) in the same directory , @abshi

Comment: Both files are in the directory `/Users/CJ/Desktop/HWA`

Comment: What is your current directory (`pwd`) when you run the script?  Rule of thumb when you get this kind of error - use an absolute path name for the file, not a relative one.

Answer (score 2):

"How can I read the file which is in the same directory as that of my python script?"

```
import os
here = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filename = 'file2.txt'
filepath = os.path.join(here, filename)
linestring = open(filepath).read()
print linestring
```

Else the file is searched in your current working directory, not in the directory where your script is.